# Best practice for returning a list from a repository in the service layer in Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller, crud-repository

I'm working on a Java project and I'm unsure about the best practice for returning a list from a repository in the service layer. I've come across two different approaches and I'm seeking advice on which one is considered better or more efficient.

Way #1

```
    public List<SubjectModel> getSubjectList(int codeId) {
        List<SubjectModel> subjList = new ArrayList<>();

        subjList.addAll(subjectRepository.findByCodeId(String.valueOf(codeId)));

        return subjList ;
    }
```

or way #2

```
    public List<SubjectModel> getSubjectList(int codeId) {

        return subjectRepository.findByCodeId(String.valueOf(codeId));
    }
```

I'm unsure if it's necessary to create a separate variable (subjList) in Way #1 or if Way #2, which directly returns the repository result, is more preferable. Are there any advantages or disadvantages to either approach? Which one is considered the best practice in the industry?

Comment: It's a `private` method? That means you have full control over how the resulting `List` will be used, so you can use that to decide. it's probably going to be way #2.

Comment: It always depends on usage and purpose. If your only action is to drop the list into an API response, there is nothing much of a difference and `way2` is "ok" due to simplicity. If your service is used as a step on a larger process and `mutability` may become an issue I (personally) may prefer `way1`. If it is not a service method but object state maybe following sonar recommendations https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2384

Comment: If your use case is simple, I would recommend going for the second option. There is no need for an additional variable that doesn't serve any real purpose. However, I do have a suggestion regarding your second example. I strongly advise against calling methods inside setters, especially when it involves calling String.valueOf(). It is considered a bad practice, and I personally try to avoid it.

Comment: @daniu ops! I edited my code. It's public. Does way#1 take more memory than way#2?

Comment: @BrunoMiguel why it's a bad practice? Can you explain further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any explicit reason why you want to have it in an `ArrayList`, then there is no need to wrap it additionally. I would go with way #2. The important part for the caller is the signature of the method, which defines `List<>` as the return type in both cases. way #1 just makes it harder to understand the code, because it's more bloated and everyone reading it would be wondering why you put the result in an `ArrayList`. If there are any specific reasons, then you should at least add a comment explaining why. But the default way to go would be #2 for me.

Comment: Does way#1 take more memory than way#2?

Comment: Yes but probably not significatntly more. You basically copy over references to the other list. So you pay for holding those references twice until the garbage collector kicks in. But references are usually quite small compared to the data itself. That is sth. that you don't have to worry about under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

If you develop a popular product and need to print the number log of SubjectModel in online service?

```
private List<SubjectModel> getSubjectList(int codeId) {
    List<SubjectModel> subjList = subjectRepository.findByCodeId(String.valueOf(codeId));
    log.info("there is {} SubjectModels", subjList.size())
    return subjList ;
}
```

But this is not necessary, during the development process, it is fine according to actual needs